# MySql "Many to One" table design

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-schema

I am new to DB design and I am having some trouble finding info on how to define a "Many to One" relationship. I can find all sorts of info on "One to Many" and "Many to Many" but nothing on "Many to One". My hangup is how to store the data. What I have is one table called "Categories" then I have another table called "Inventory", each "Inventory" item can belong to multiple "Categories".

How do I store multiple "Categories" in a single "Inventory" row? Should I have a intermediate table that stores the "Categories" ID with the corresponding "Inventory" ID? Or would adding something like a JSON string that has the "Categories" ID's in the "Inventory" row be the right way to do this? Or is there a way to store an Array of "Categories" ID's in the "Inventory" row?

Thanks allot for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the correct term of `Many to One` is `One to Many`. simply create a table like this,

```
CREATE TABLE Categories
(
    CategoryID INT Primary KEY,
    CategoryName
);

CREATE TABLE InventoryList
(
    ProductID INT Primary KEY,
    CategoryID INT,
    ProductName VARCHAR(50),
    CONSTRAINT tb_fk FOREIGN KEY (CategoryID) REFERENCES Categories(CategoryID)
);
```

Comment: Hi, I'm also new to mysql, may I ask what tb_fk is? I understand that (CategoryID) field is referencing Categories(CategoryID) for its input

Comment: @theo123490 here tb_fk is the name of the constraint. Well, it may not be necessary. If you omit, the Mysql engine assigns it automatically.

Answer (score 5):

First I would suggest that you download [mysql workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) - it gives you a nice visual db design mode so you can see how things hang together (creates foreign key relationships etc etc for you).

In this instance this is actually a many-to-many relationship. as such you will need a category table, an inventory table and a category_has_inventory table (or inventory_has_category depending on semantics) where you store the id of the inventory and category in each tuple - workbench even creates this table for you when using the many-to-many relationship tool.

Pop back on here if you need further help.

IF a category can only contain one inventory item then you could create a one-to many relationship by adding inventory_id to the category table but that sounds wrong to me.

Comment: Thanks Ian... That is exactly what I was looking for... I didn't realize that this was a "Many to Many" relationship... I was just thinking of one row not the entire table... Thanks again!

Comment: it is a many-to-many relationship if an inventory can appear in multiple categories and a category can display multiple inventories (which is what I think you actually need). If a category can contain one and only one inventory (not much of a category in my mind) then you would store the inventory id in the category table against the respective category.

Answer (score 4):

"Many to one" is just "One to many" looked at from the other end.

Just add a column `inventory_id` to the `Categories` table.

If not only each "Inventory" item can belong to multiple "Categories" but also each "Categories" item can belong to multiple "Inventory" items, than you have a many-to-many relation for which you need a intermediate table with `category_id` and `inventory_id`.